# Redirect ALL get parameters to another domain in Nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx

Only answers I can find for this have specific parameters and don't work if the parameters change.

I have a URL coming in such as:

`/logs.php?user_id=10032&account_id=10099&message=0&interval=1&online=1&rsid=65374826&action=update&ids=827,9210,82930&session_id=1211546313-1602275138`

I need to redirect this url to a completely different domain and file but keep the get params.

So it ends up redirecting to:

`https://example.com/the_logger.php?REPEAT_ALL_GET_PARAMETERS_HERE`

---

Here is what I have unsuccessfully tried so far:

```
location logs.php
{
    rewrite https://example.com/the_logger.php?$args last;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to match the url or redirect. I think I'm misunderstanding the logic of nginx confs. If it were .htaccess I think I'd be okay. I can put a few more examples here if need be of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you state this is a redirect and not reverse proxying a request, I would use the `return` directive to tell the client to do a `301` or `302`. Using the [return](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) directive is the simpler and [more recommend approach](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/) to redirecting a client.

Something like should do what you want:

```
location /logs {
    return 302 https://example.com/the_logger.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Where `$is_args` would output a `?` if and only if the query string is not empty, and `$args` is the query string itself

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Comment: Also am I correct in thinking the "$arg" is supposed to be "$args"? I received this error when it was $arg. `unknown "arg" variable`.

Comment: Sorry. I Defined it correctly but the example was wrong. Updated.